# Scheduled jobs didn't trigger as per the daily schedule

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-agent-job

My production environment is set up to run jobs on a daily basis and they have been running as per the schedule for years.

Today they did not trigger, and I don't know what the reason could be.  I found recommendations online to go through SQL Server's logs, but don't know what I should be looking for.

These jobs have no end date in the scheduler.

Comment: Are your jobs enabled?

Comment: Is your SQL Server Agent service running?

Comment: @AdrianChodkowski, his SQL Server Agent service has to be running to view the job scheduler.  Thought the same thing until I read over it a second time.  Very strange issue, wonder if there was an outage during that time.

Comment: Thanks Guys, somehow i didnt check that some jobs are enabled.sorry for this.